# Cómo poner una URL en laravel y js, al usar el helper asset en un src

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, json

Estoy recibiendo unos datos relacionados con la base de datos, para luego mostrarlos en una ventana modal, todo perfecto al recibir los datos, el problema radica al intentar mostrar una imagen, puesto que no puedo usar ningún `helper` de dirección de laravel porque js no lo permite; al abrir el inspector de elementos se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: inspector de elementos src asset]

Dentro del `src` debería mostrar el típico `https:localhost...`.

Este es el código js:

```
$.post(
  path,
  data,
  function(data){
    //console.log(response);
    table.html("");

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){          
      var fila = "<tr>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Nombre_item + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Cantidad + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Color_item_int + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Color_item_ext + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Talla + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Tipografia + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Fondo + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Mensaje_cliente + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" +'<img src="{{ asset('+ data[i].Ruta_foto_cliente +') }}>">'+ "</td>";
      fila +="</tr>";

      table.append(fila);
    };
  },
  'json'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de poner una url en laravel:

La **Primera** en un archivo `.blade.php`: En ocaciones tendemos a colocar nuestro código en secciones (`@section("script")`) en el cual el `helper asset()` funcionaria de maravilla de la siguiente manera:

```
fila += '<td><img src="{{ asset('/') }}'+data[i].Ruta_foto_cliente+'" ></td>';
```

y aun así puede ser incomodo e inseguro manejarlo de dicha forma, ya que dicho código puede ser hasta editado desde cualquier navegador.

La **Segunda** es en un archivo `.js`: es la mas correcta (y creo la que utilizas)y ademas es una forma de tener ordenada nuestro proyecto evitando mesclar código `php` y `javascript`.

Generalmente en laravel se tiene una archivo principal que muchas veces se llama `layout.blade.php` el cual se extiende a lo largo del proyecto él cual es el lugar ideal para poner el siguiente codigo:

```
<script>
    var url_global='{{url("/")}}';
    var asset_global='{{asset("/")}}';
    var asset_user_global='{{asset("/img_user")}}';//solo es un ejemplo en caso de que tengas un mapeo organizado de carpetas. 
</script>
```

Y puedes poner las que desees, una nota importante es que si no utilizas el `layout` principal lo puedes poner en el archivo correspondiente, pero bueno: una vez que tengas estas variables globales puedes crear un archivo `.js` en la carpeta **public** de laravel. En lo personal siempre los pongo una carpeta llamada **misjs**, entonces imaginemos que mi archivo se llama `users.js` en el cual tendrías tu código `javascript`.Entonces llamamos a dicho archivo:

```
<script src="{{asset('/misjs/users.js')}}"></sript>
```

Y tu linea código `js` seria:

```
fila += "<td>" +"<img src='"+asset_global+"/"+data[i].Ruta_foto_cliente+"') }}>'>"+ "</td>";
```

Hasta aquí la respuesta. Pero ahora un par de ...

**Consejos**

**NO** mezcles codigo `php` con `javascript`.

**Define** el uso de comillas simple (')  y comillas doble ("), si bien el interprete no los confunde se debe de tener un estándar de codificación.

**Saber** distinguir entre `{{}}` y `{!! !!}` los cuales son propios de `blade`, sin embargo son diferentes muy diferentes, te explico en un ejemplo:

Se tiene un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
$obj->html='<script>alert("hola a todos");</script>';
```

Utilizando `{{$obj->html}}` imprimira : `<script>alert("hola a todos");<script>`, y no habrá ningún problema.

Utilizando `{!! $obj->html !!}` embebe el código y en vez de imprimirlo te mostrara la alerta con el mensaje :`hola a todos`. y esto es un **PELIGRO!!!**.

Asi que se debe de tener en cuenta mucho cuando utilizar uno y cuando el otro, ambos son muy útiles cuando se los utiliza de buena manera.

Comment: Funciono perfecto muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicar de manera detallada todo, tendre muy presentes los consejos .

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar una variable global en una vista blade por ejemplo en el layout.blade.php y poner

```
<script>
   var asset = '{{ asset('') }}' // declaras la ruta que apunta a public
</script>
```

Y ya luego en tu archivo js

```
$.post(
  path,
  data,
  function(data){
    //console.log(response);
    table.html("");

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){          
      var fila = "<tr>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Nombre_item + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Cantidad + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Color_item_int + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Color_item_ext + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Talla + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Tipografia + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Fondo + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" + data[i].Mensaje_cliente + "</td>";
      fila += "<td>" +'<img src="' asset + data[i].Ruta_foto_cliente +'"/>'+ "</td>";
      fila +="</tr>";

      table.append(fila);
    };
  },
  'json'
);
```

Comment: amigo muchas gracias en esencia es eso, me hubiera gustado saber un poco mas pero de igual manera me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Añade una función que sea global, por ejemplo en el layout de tu aplicación:

```
<script>
    function asset(file) {
        return '{{ asset('') }}' + file;
    }
</script>
```

Si quieres llamarlo desde Vue tienes que registrar un método:

```
methods: {
    asset: function(file) {
        return asset(file)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar {!! !!} de blade para imprimir un texto en HTML en raw.

```
fila += "<td>" +'<img src="{!! asset('+ data[i].Ruta_foto_cliente +') !!}>">'+ "</td>";
```

Al loro con esto, no lo uses en un sitio donde el usuario normal pueda insertarte código HTML o JS, ya que ejecutarías su código, lo que se llama XSS (Cross-site scripting) .