# No me encuentra la ruta laravel con jquery ajax e investigado y intentado de todo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

[image: Por ejemplo aqui si me funcionan bien mis 2 select dinamicos que tengo en el modal nuevo registro el problema es cuando voy al boton de editar que me dejan de funcionar y ya no me encuentran la ruta no se si tiene que ver algo el id que toma o que pero en si mi ruta ya no me la encuentra]

en esta parte ya estoy en el boton de editar el problema que tengo es que me dejan de funcionar mis select dinamicos que me deberian funcionar igual que los de registro y no se cual puede ser el problema la verdad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi ajax que esta en una funciona este es el que no me encuentra la ruta que quiero cuando le doy al boton editar me deja de funcionar

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select[name="departamento"]').on('change', function(){
        var id_departamento = $(this).val();
        if(id_departamento) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'municipios_dinamico/'+id_departamento,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {

                    $('select[name="municipio_id"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(idx, municipio){

                        $('select[name="municipio_id"]').append('<option value="'+ municipio.id +'">' + municipio.nombre + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="municipio_id"]').empty();
        }

    });

});
```

esta es mi ruta la cual no me encuentra

```
Route::get('municipios_dinamico/{id}',[
    'as'=>'municipios_dinamico',
    'uses'=>'icf@municipio_dinamico_get'
]);
```

esta es  mi funcion ala cual va mi ruta

```
public static function municipio_dinamico_get(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            $municipios=municipios::municipios_dinamico($id);
            return response()->json($municipios);
        }
    }
```

y esta es  mi funcion de mi modelo donde traiga los datos

```
 public static  function municipios_dinamico($id){
        return municipios::where('id_departamento','=',$id)->get();
    }
```

Comment: no creo que lo hayas buscado, te aconsejo ver el siguiente link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194167/c%C3%B3mo-poner-una-url-en-laravel-y-js-al-usar-el-helper-asset-en-un-src/194230#194230

Comment: si e investigado la verdad pero no en ese link ya llevo varios dias vere el link a ver si encuentro una solucion gracias

Comment: tengo mi archivo js en public  asi como menciona en el link que me dejaste pero de igual forma me sigue el problema que no me encuentra la ruta alguna solucion revise y no se cual puede ser la causa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En inicio el unico problema que veo es:

```
url: 'municipios_dinamico/'+id_departamento,
```

la cual no se dirige a la url correcta, dices que tienes tu `js` en la carpeta public, lo que debes de hacer es:

En el archivo `blade` principal debes de añadir una variable js global, entonces:

Tu archivo `principal.blade.php` debe contener:

```
<script>
    var url_global='{{url("/")}}';
</script>
```

Y utilizar la variable `url_global`, en todos tus archivos `.js`.

Entonces tu codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
url: url_global+'municipios_dinamico/'+id_departamento,
```

Comment: muchas gracias me solucionaste el problema te agradezco